# Disable roo open/close logging

Tags: spring-roo, spring-tool-suite

we're working on a project that uses Spring Roo and there is one quite annoying detail that comes into play when team woks on the same code (in brances).

We work in STS (it opens Roo shell automatically) and the problem is that every time Roo shell gets opened/closed it logs time into "log.roo", so if there is more than one dev. that work on the same codebase in branches we end up with merging these logs from time to time.

We could add "log.roo" to ignore in our SCM but having log about what was actually done using Roo is rather handy thing.

Is there a way to tweak Roo (or STS) so it won't log this junk (open/close time records) that we end up merging?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you maintain a copy of the log.roo file? This is the approach that I use, a file named script.roo that allows me to edit it if necessary (for removing or adding comments) and it also allows me to ignore log.roo in the SCM

Comment: Do you mean shell scripts here? If so - sounds a bit kludgey to my mind. Except that, we develop under different platforms (Windows/Linux), so I do not really want to mess with platform-specific builds, etc.
I'll look for his as an option though, so thanks for the idea.
BTW, for your scripts, do you use SCM hooks (like the ones in git), IDE means, or run your scripts manually?

Comment: Sorry for the name. I simply rename log.roo with another name (core.roo, if you prefer) and it only contains Roo commands, that works in every platform where Roo can be installed. Plus some useful comments (I mean, for other programmers that share the code). The "script", or Roo commands, can be invoked using the Roo command: script --file.